# Excluding UIActivities from UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using `UIActivityViewController` to share a **.CSV** file that can be opened by my app if the user has my app. I only want to my user to share using web, mail, or airdrop.

This is more or less my code

```
 //Initialize activityVC. Activity item is [self] because I'm adopting UIActivityItemSource Protocol.
let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [self], applicationActivities: nil) 

//Here I'm trying to exclude everything but web, mail, and airdrop.
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePostToFacebook, UIActivityTypePostToFlickr, UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToVimeo, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll]
      if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
           activityVC.excludedActivityTypes?.append(UIActivityTypeOpenInIBooks)
      } else {
           // Fallback on earlier versions
      }

//Present VC
self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

So my problem is, even though I've tried to exclude everything available to me via code, I'm still getting random applications like slack and notes showing up when i don't want my user sharing **.CSV** with that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot exclude apps from `UIActivityViewController`, because these apps were declared that they can open and handle .csv file types (via `Document types` in `Info.plist`).
If you don't want to show these apps, you can share file directly to the destination. For example for email you can use `MFMailComposeViewController` .

Comment: That makes sense. I want the user to see a UIActivityViewController and I don't want to subclass. But I just tried it in notes and it looks the can open the file from notes app into my app. TY for a swift reply. So although i'm not limiting the user as much as I'd like, They should be able to decide for themselves where they want to send it to.